# Sharepoint 2013 O365 App cannot create a list in a sub site

Tags: list, web-part, client-object-model, app, visual-studio-2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 app that can create a list in the site that it deploys too but it cannot create a list in a sub site where the app has not been deployed and trusted. Is there any way to get around this or will I need to install and trust the app for every sub site I wish to create a list?

Comment: Is this provider hosted or SharePoint hosted?

Answer (score 1):

have you  deployment of the list in a Web scope?

You should add the list in the feature and set configuration of feature in Web scope

[image]

Comment: The screenshot above is not necessarily valid for Apps. SharePoint components deployed through the App web will only have 'Web' scope in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Check your App permissions in the App manifest. Remember, that if you are carrying out any actions from your App to your Host web you will need to grant the App permissions to do so.

You will also need to specify in your App how you will provision to other Webs below the current one, whether you iterate through the Web collection or specify manually is up to you as your App will not be aware of the other Subsites other than the Host Web where you are installed.

If you want a List to be automatically provisioned on every subsite, then I would use a Remote Event Receiver that fires on WebProvisioned then Install this App to the RootWeb which will provision the Event Receiver.